# Juju: How to connect to already bootstrapped environment

Tags: juju

I have bootstrapped a manual environment from my laptop. How can I access the environment from another computer?

Comment: I think you need to copy the `.jenv` from `~/.juju/environments/`, but I'm not confident enough in my memory to give you a full answer. It's an area that's worth investigating though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to successfully access the environment you need the following:

- The file `~/.juju/environments/<environment-name>.jenv`
- The environment config for that environment located in `~/.juju/environments.yaml`

Using these two you can connect to the environment. However, for `juju ssh` to work, you need to add the ssh key of the second computer to the Juju environment.

This can be done using `juju authorised-keys import lp:some_launchpad_user` or `juju authorised-keys add <public-key>`.